# PHP mail() troubles Mac

Tags: apache, email, terminal, php

I am trying to send an email from my mac using the php `mail()` function, but I cannot seem to get it to work. I can start `sendmail` from the terminal with no errors, and have edited my system's `php.ini` file found at `/private/etc` to set `sendmail_path` to `/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i` and uncommented it. I created a simple php script:

```
<?php
mail("<my email address>", "Test", "This is a Test Message", "From:" . "<another of my email addresses>");
echo "Mail Sent\n";
?>
```

and I am running it from the terminal using `php mail.php`. It echoes "Mail Sent", however it seems that no email is being sent. It is getting lost somewhere, but I have no clue where. I have restarted Apache, double checked that `sendmail` is running, yet nothing works. Any ideas?

Comment: try to check your bulk or spam mails.

Comment: are you applying those brackets with your email address ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not send mail using "mail()" function from your localhost, for that you have to host your code on any hosting provider then you can send the mail from it

see this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) for more information.

if you want to send mail from localhost then you go for specific API like, if you want to send mail using your gmail credential then try this [php mailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)